# The actual utilization of Ref Cursor is at Database level not at the Database Client level. Is this statement correct?

Tags: cursors

From my understanding, the purpose of a ref cursor is to pass a Result Set among procedures/functions(at the DB level) through a "pointer" without passing the actual Result Set which can consume a lot of memory(At DB level).

Say I'm using a java client to talk with my database. I'm calling a stored procedure that returns a ref cursor. At java level I can obtain the result set pointed by the ref cursor as follows.

```
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(1);
```

Here, the result set is already in the memory inside the stmt object. Even though it is a pointer that was returned, at java level we already have the result set in memory. Therefore, say you only have one simple procedure that returns one result set obtained from a simple SELECT. And you call that procedure from java client and retrieve the result set. In this particular case,

1. Returning a result set

and

2. Returning a ref cursor to that result set

both would have the same resource consumption.

Is my understanding correct?

Note: This is a general question. The database could be Oracle/PostgreSQL or any other database that supports SQL Ref Cursor type